# Install latest Ubuntu in dual UEFI boot with windows 8.1 64bits

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have an 64bits windows 8.1 pc with UEFI and I am not able to dual boot the latest version of Ubuntu 64 bits on it, it says that it doesn't support EFI. Need help pls, and I don't want to change UEFI for traditional bios

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it says that it doesn't support EFI." Provide a screen shot (digital photo) or at least an *exact quote* of whatever's on the screen. A summary of an error message is seldom good enough and is *never* as good as the exact error message in context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- Disable Secure Boot in your BIOS;
- Disable the "Fast Startup Boot" in Windows;
- Use [RUFUS](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a bootable USB Drive with GPT Partition;

Take a look [**in this guide**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). It will help you!